# Getting error while publishing blazor wasm application

Tags: .net-core, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I can successfully run blazor wasm application local host but when I am publishing
Getting error as **"dotnet.exe" exited with code 1.**
I am using .net6

Below is **Server.csproj** code

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>    
  </PropertyGroup>

 

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper" Version="11.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.123" />
    <PackageReference Include="DinkToPdf" Version="1.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="runtime.win.System.Console" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="runtime.win.System.Net.Primitives" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.FileSystem" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Primitives" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Encoding.Extensions" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Targets" Version="6.0.0-preview.4.21253.7" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\PB.Client.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\PB.Shared.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="libwkhtmltox.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

Could you please help to solve this error

Comment: Anything more in the event viewer?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more information around the error, but if I had to guess at this point, the error is probably during dotnet restore because you're references include internal implementation packages that aren't meant to be consumed directly. Try removing the packages that start with runtime.win (see https://www.nuget.org/packages/runtime.win.System.Console)

Comment: Thanks for your comments.https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/26061
This link helps me to solve mentioned error